# Calls to successive calls on repeater with XML datasource is not binding new data

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have the following Page_Load function...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  XmlDataSource1.Data = GetXmlFromFile(Request.QueryString["file"]);
  XmlDataSource1.DataBind();

  Repeater1.DataBind();                      
}
```

The page in which this Page_Load resides is called by a parent page.  Each time this Page_Load gets called the value of "file" in the query string will be different.  So each time I will be receiving the XML contents from a different file which are inserted into the XmlDataSource and then bound against by the Repeater.  Getting the XML data from the file works great but when I bind against the repeater that only works the first time through Page_Load.  Each time after that when this code is executed the same results from the first XML file are displayed in the repeater.

What am I missing here.  How can I get the XML data to be bound against the repeater on each page load instead of just the first one?

Comment: You said that getting the XML works great.  Is that just the first time?  Or do subsequent page loads also grab the expected data?  What happens if you browse directly to the page, supplying your own query string?

Comment: Hi Joel getting the XML actually works every time, I have traced through to verify this but the XML which is bound against is always from the first call.  Browsing directly to the page using my own query string doesn't seem to work either.  Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation turns out the problem is a caching flag which is set to default true on XmlDataSource's.  Other data source types like SqlDataSource do not have this flag enabled.

This is more fully outlined in the following article [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200717051712/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/ranganh/archive/2006/04/28/76638.aspx)

Upon disabling the caching feature everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Tried creating a new XmlDataSource on each load?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  XmlDataSource source = new XmlDataSource();
  source.ID = "MyDS";
  source.Data = GetXmlFromFile(Request.QueryString["file"]);
  source.DataBind();

  Repeater1.DataSource = source;
  Repeater1.DataBind();                      
}
```

Comment: I thought this idea would've worked for sure.  But no.  Same issue.

Comment: Did you remove the existing XmlDatasource/references to it from the markup before trying this?

Comment: Yeh.  I was actually receiving errors if I didn't remove them first.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, set the source.ID to a newly generated value each Page_Load. I have a suspicion that there's some funkiness going on with how the XmlDataSource caches its data.

Comment: Your curiosity was spot on!  That worked.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to duplicate the problem with a simple implementation that follows your main concept.

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["file"] != null)
    {
        XmlDataSource XmlDataSource1 = new XmlDataSource();
        XmlDataSource1.DataFile = "~/App_Data/" + Request.QueryString["file"];
        Repeater1.DataSource = XmlDataSource1;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This works when I browse to "Default.aspx?file=West.xml" where west.xml is an xml file in my App_Data folder.  When I enter another existing xml file in the query string, it performs as expected. It's quick n' dirty, but maybe it will give you some idea when comparing it against your existing code.

Comment: Yeh I'm not sure why this method would not work for me.  Maybe because I am setting the data of the xml data source to a string value instead of a file? zincorp's answer worked for me but I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: That's correct. The DataFile property will only map to a physical file, whereas Data will allow dynamic XML